# Google cloud Network Bandwidth is Slow

Tags: performance, networking, google-cloud-platform

My Website is running on Google cloud . Some pages are taking 5-10 seconds to load jacascript and CSS. How can I increase network speed

Answer (score 1):

I can give you some recommendations to improve your website's performance:

1. Test your network performance:
   There are some tools you can use for this task,

- [Iperf](https://iperf.fr/) is a tool to measure the bandwidth and the quality of a network link. You can find an easy tutorial in this [link](https://openmaniak.com/iperf.php)
- [Netperf](https://hewlettpackard.github.io/netperf/) is another good network testing tool.
- [traceroute](https://www.pcwdld.com/traceroute) is a computer network diagnostic tool to measure and display packets’ routes across a network.

2. It is important to keep in mind that the latency also depends on where your computer is located and where your instance is. I mean if you are in Australia and your Instance is working in the US you will experience high latency.
3. Check the CPU and memory usage, if your application is consuming all the resources in your Instance the performance on your website will be so bad. Keep in mind that the more virtual CPUs, the more networking throughput you get.

Additionally , I recommend the following documents that may help you with your issue.

1. [Make the Web Faster](https://developers.google.com/speed/?hl=en-US&utm_source=PSI&utm_medium=incoming-link&utm_campaign=PSI)
2. [5 steps to better GCP network performance](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/5-steps-to-better-gcp-network-performance?hl=ml)
3. [TCP optimization for network performance in Google Cloud and hybrid scenarios](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/tcp-optimization-for-network-performance-in-gcp-and-hybrid)

On the other hand, I recommend you to review the following guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to provide a better context on what you are doing and what you want to achieve.

Comment: How large is the Javascript and the CSS?
What is the size of the VM in which you are running the webserver?
What speed network connection does the client taking a long time to load the javascript and CSS have?
The basic idea is to figure-out whether this slowness is loss, a low-speed connection, or something else by looking at those things, as well as perhaps snapshots of statistics (netstat -s) and a packet trace (tcpdump) taking at the sending side if not both.